# Tensorflow GPU stopped working

Tags: tensorflow

#### Reproducing the issue

I had tensorflow running a few days ago, but it stopped working. Upon testing it with the tutorial code, both [`mnist_softmax`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py) and [`mnist_deep`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_deep.py) fail. Tensorflow is succeeding in running the simple [`helloworld`](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/1_Introduction/helloworld.py) content.

#### What I've tried

- As with [delton137](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8879#issuecomment-323851728), I've tried setting `allow_growth` to True or the  `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` to 0.1, but this does not help.
- I've tried reinstalling my `cudnn` files.

#### Additional notes

I don't remember making any changes to my Tensorflow installation or my CUDA/cuDNN setup, so my best guess is that this might be an issue with a driver that auto-updated.

#### System information

- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**: No. Issue is reproducible using code from tensorflow tutorials.
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: source
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: v1.3.0-rc2-20-g0787eee 1.3.0
- **Python version**: Python 3.5.2 (default, Aug 18 2017, 17:48:00)
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**: N/A
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: CUDA release 8.0, V8.0.61 / libcudnn.so.6.0.21
- **GPU model and memory**: GeForce GTX 1080, 8GB, on 384.90 driver

#### Source code / logs

For `helloworld` code in REPL

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2017-10-26 21:56:00.418991: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-26 21:56:00.419027: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-26 21:56:00.419036: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-26 21:56:00.419046: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-26 21:56:00.419054: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-26 21:56:00.565143: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-10-26 21:56:00.565417: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 6.48GiB
2017-10-26 21:56:00.565432: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2017-10-26 21:56:00.565437: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2017-10-26 21:56:00.565447: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

For `python3 mnist_deep.py`

```
2017-10-26 21:37:56.993479: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:371] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2017-10-26 21:37:56.993560: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:338] could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
2017-10-26 21:37:56.993580: F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:672] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms)
```

For `python3 mnist_softmax.py`

```
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 6.50GiB
2017-10-26 21:53:16.150706: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2017-10-26 21:53:16.150712: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2017-10-26 21:53:16.150723: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
2017-10-26 21:53:16.422081: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:366] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2017-10-26 21:53:16.422132: W tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:1756] attempting to perform BLAS operation using StreamExecutor without BLAS support
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1306, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(100, 784), b.shape=(784, 10), m=100, n=10, k=784
         [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0/_9, Variable/read)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_softmax.py", line 78, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "mnist_softmax.py", line 65, in main
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(100, 784), b.shape=(784, 10), m=100, n=10, k=784
         [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0/_9, Variable/read)]]

Caused by op 'MatMul', defined at:
  File "mnist_softmax.py", line 78, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "mnist_softmax.py", line 42, in main
    y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1844, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1289, in _mat_mul
    transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InternalError (see above for traceback): Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(100, 784), b.shape=(784, 10), m=100, n=10, k=784
         [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0/_9, Variable/read)]]
```

Here is the output of `nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.90                 Driver Version: 384.90                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 34%   51C    P0    35W / 180W |   1340MiB /  8110MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1250      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           785MiB |
|    0      2426      G   compiz                                       359MiB |
|    0      3840      G   ...-token=44A975F4EE134A1BF9C8CD1C7223C977   107MiB |
|    0      4944      G   ...-token=4F87ADEE5575E9B5125D41E08D43BF0E    83MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: OT: how the gpu works for you ? it's worth the money ?

Comment: I've run into this problem also.  Using AWS `p2-xlarge` with single Nvidia K80.  It will run for 20-60 minutes, but the GPU will just stop.  The process is still listed in `nvidia-smi` and the CPU is still at 100%, but the GPU utilization falls to zero.  I have a theory that the GPU is faulting and the CPU is continuing the work but doing it very slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close sessions active in other processes. Please follow this thread -

[TensorFlow: InternalError: Blas SGEMM launch failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337728/tensorflow-internalerror-blas-sgemm-launch-failed)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; unfortunately, I don't have sessions open in any other processes (as you can see from the result for `nvidia-smi`)